# Why not change position in getView() android?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

position does not change after add new data in arraylist.

public class ItemsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;

public ItemsAdapter(Context context,
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
    this.context = context;
    data = arraylist;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    //=========HERE DATA IS COMING CORRECTLY===============
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
        System.out.println("Get Couunt Size : - "
                + data.get(i).get("Title"));
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    Holder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new Holder();

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        holder.tvTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        holder.tvNotes = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvNotes);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    //=========HERE POSITION ALWAYS 0===============
    System.out.println("Position:::" + position + " Title : - "
            + data.get(position).get("Title") + ", Notes :- "
            + data.get(position).get("Note"));

    holder.tvTitle.setText(data.get(position).get("Title"));
    holder.tvNotes.setText(data.get(position).get("Note"));
    return convertView;
}

private static class Holder {
    TextView tvTitle, tvNotes;
}
```

}

i also call notifyDataSetChanged() method in main activity.

add data using dialogbox.

```
dlAddNote = new Dialog(this);
    dlAddNote.setTitle("Add Note");
    dlAddNote.setContentView(R.layout.add_note_dialog);

    final EditText etTitle = (EditText) dlAddNote
            .findViewById(R.id.etTitle);
    final EditText etNotes = (EditText) dlAddNote
            .findViewById(R.id.etNotes);

    Button btnSave = (Button) dlAddNote.findViewById(R.id.btnSave);

    Button btnCancel = (Button) dlAddNote.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);

    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            hashMap.put("Title", etTitle.getText().toString());
            hashMap.put("Note", etNotes.getText().toString());
            System.out.println("Title" + etTitle.getText().toString());
            System.out.println("Note" + etNotes.getText().toString());
            arrayListLeft.add(hashMap);

            dlAddNote.dismiss();

            leftAdapter = new ItemsAdapter(KeepGuiActivity.this,
                    arrayListLeft);
            listViewLeft.setAdapter(leftAdapter);
            leftAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dlAddNote.cancel();
        }
    });

    dlAddNote.show();
```

i am using custom dialog box and add data in runtime but dose not change data.

Comment: you mean it is not displaying by the time you add an item??

Comment: yes. i add data but does't change position in adapter

Comment: can you post the code where you add the data.

Comment: is the dialog only called once?

Comment: no.. when i click on add button then every time dialog will be display and add data in hashmap..

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin, it's showing only first item, after that it's not showing updated item, everytime position is returning 0 :(

Comment: This code: `leftAdapter = new ItemsAdapter(KeepGuiActivity.this, arrayListLeft); listViewLeft.setAdapter(leftAdapter);` should be in onCreateView(). You shouldn't keep creating a new adapter every time you add an item.

Comment: i also try this but it same problem..

Comment: `getItem()` should return data.get(position).  `getItemId()` should return position.

Comment: just checked your code..works fine without any change and positin value does change.I hope the scope of your variables are on activity level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**problem:**

```
dlAddNote.dismiss();
```

What it is doing is that it will `dismiss` your dialog and wont execute the code after it so that is why the `listview` is not updating.

**solution:**

call it before the `dismiss` method and check if `leftAdapter` is `null` to avoid recreating your listview over and over again.

```
btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        hashMap.put("Title", etTitle.getText().toString());
        hashMap.put("Note", etNotes.getText().toString());
        System.out.println("Title" + etTitle.getText().toString());
        System.out.println("Note" + etNotes.getText().toString());
        arrayListLeft.add(hashMap);

        if(leftAdapter == null) {
           leftAdapter = new ItemsAdapter(KeepGuiActivity.this,  arrayListLeft);
           listViewLeft.setAdapter(leftAdapter);
        }
        leftAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        dlAddNote.dismiss();
    }
});
```

Comment: @EleshBaraiya post the whole ItemsAdapter class

Comment: @EleshBaraiya what is the result you got from above code?

Comment: thanks friend for give me ans.. its mistake of layout.

Answer (score 1):

I test your code and works very well. It shows all the data I entered in the dialog box. 
(FYI: I declare all your variables in Activity's scope because you don't show it to your sample code). I put the Activity's code below:

```
public class KeepGuiActivity extends Activity {

private Dialog dlAddNote;
private ListView listViewLeft;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayListLeft;
private ItemsAdapter leftAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listViewLeft = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    arrayListLeft = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog();
        }

    });
}

private void showDialog() {
    dlAddNote = new Dialog(this);
    dlAddNote.setTitle("Add Note");
    dlAddNote.setContentView(R.layout.add_note_dialog);

    final EditText etTitle = (EditText) dlAddNote
            .findViewById(R.id.etTitle);
    final EditText etNotes = (EditText) dlAddNote
            .findViewById(R.id.etNotes);

    Button btnSave = (Button) dlAddNote.findViewById(R.id.btnSave);

    Button btnCancel = (Button) dlAddNote.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);

    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            hashMap.put("Title", etTitle.getText().toString());
            hashMap.put("Note", etNotes.getText().toString());
            System.out.println("Title" + etTitle.getText().toString());
            System.out.println("Note" + etNotes.getText().toString());
            arrayListLeft.add(hashMap);

            dlAddNote.dismiss();

            leftAdapter = new ItemsAdapter(KeepGuiActivity.this,
                    arrayListLeft);
            listViewLeft.setAdapter(leftAdapter);
            leftAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dlAddNote.cancel();
        }
    });

    dlAddNote.show();
}
```

If the above code does not work for you, tell me if you use code for returning specific item from the adapter. Also, you can update the below methods of ItemsAdapter to return actual data:

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return data.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```